Will the accelerometer's measurement noise be related to the signal being measured?
I'm new to signal measurement, and I apologize if this is a silly question.
I want to know if the accelerometer's measurement noise is related to the signal being measured.
I'm conducting a study on the optimal placement of accelerometer sensors. In this study, I need to consider the measurement noise in the accelerometers. I plan to start by using numerical simulation results for my study. Since the responses obtained from numerical simulations do not include noise, I need to manually add a certain level of noise to the simulation results. I am considering two methods for adding noise. The first method, as follows, adds noise that is unrelated to the calculated response.
l=5;
noise=randn(size(Y,1),1);
noise=noise/norm(noise);
Y=Y+noise*l;
The second method, as follows, adds noise that is related to the calculated response, where the larger the response, the greater the noise added.
l=0.1;
noise=randn(size(Y,1),1);
noise=noise/norm(noise);
Y=Y+noise*norm(Y)*l;
I want to know which way is closer to the actual situation. Thank you.
The reason I initially divided by the norm was that I saw this approach being used in some numerical computation papers. Thank you all for the reminder.

Naumova, V., & Pereverzyev, S. V. (2013). Multi-penalty regularization with a component-wise penalization. Inverse Problems, 29(7), 075002.

You could probably visit the manufacturers specs of the actual accelerometer to find such data. For what its worth, other sensors that I have dealt with have had both a signal-independent additive component as well as a signal-scaling noise component (eg image sensors).

In addition to what has been said here, one good advice from many years of signal processing practice: do not divide the noise by its norm. If you do that, it stops being Gaussian distributed. When scaling for a proper SNR, you should adjust the variance independently from the samples you've already drawn. Believe me. It's a common mistake.

@Florian The reason I initially divided by the norm was that I saw this approach being used in some numerical computation papers. I have added an image to the problem description. Now I understand the correct approach. Thank you for the reminder.

@Knut Inge Thank you!

The noise should be independent on the signal being measured, being dominated by the amplifiers in the sensor as well as the tranducer's electrical and mechanical properties. This can vary from manufacturer and technology, so best to speak with the applications support team for the specific sensor being used, and request from them the spectral density expected for the sensor you are using.
Importantly, the noise will not be a white noise process as the OP is using except at higher frequency offsets. To accurately model the noise, the noise should be shaped in frequency to capture the $1/f$ response that occurs at lower frequencies (and ultimately $1/f^2$ for longer simulations capturing the inevitable drift that will occur at DC and the increased noise floor at the lower frequency offsets). An example is this plot from Endevco Sensing Systems technical paper 324 showing the typical spectral densities for some example sensors.

I also don't understand why the OP is dividing the noise by the norm of the noise vector. Below I show an example of how I would generate the noise samples matching the results for the 87-1 sensor in the plot. Notice the units of this plot are given as a $\mu g/\sqrt{Hz}$ indicating rms magnitude units rather than power units (which would be  in units of $g^2/Hz$ as we would see in a Power Spectral Density plot). I also assume the Endevco plots represent a two-sided noise density, but this detail should be verified. The sampling rate of the resulting data is also a big consideration in representing the noise as I detail in the example MATLAB code below.
[MATLAB code to be added]

The reason I initially divided by the norm was that I saw this approach being used in some numerical computation papers. I have added an image to the problem description. Now I understand the correct approach. Thank you very much.

@bing sounds good - I will upload my Matlab code for generating the samples of a non-white noise process which you can replicate from the expected PSD for the sensor you are using (which you should be able to get from the manufacturer)
